# What is the minimal SDP answer to receive WebRTC Audio and Video?

Tags: webrtc, rtp, sdp

I am currently trying to stream WebRTC MediaStreams to my Server where it will be recorded. Sadly there is no native Java webRTC endpoint, so I want to implement this special case myself.

Now, given an offer sdp and my server's public IP, how do I construct the minimal sdp response necessary for the browser to start the DTLS handshake necessary for SRTP?

If you want to explain on a concrete example please use the sdp offer below (stemming from chrome with a single video mediaStream) and assume the server's public IP to be "12.34.56.78" :

```
v=0
o=- 8782460735244849509 3 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE video
a=msid-semantic: WMS oHpG0QpIucmqjpjl26NElSfQfQD9Lnetl3Tn
m=video 59183 RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117 96
c=IN IP4 192.168.178.37
a=rtcp:59183 IN IP4 192.168.178.37
a=candidate:1833114227 1 udp 2122063615 192.168.178.37 59183 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1833114227 2 udp 2122063615 192.168.178.37 59183 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:599844483 1 tcp 1518083839 192.168.178.37 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:599844483 2 tcp 1518083839 192.168.178.37 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:6iMBf9B5eBE6OQmW
a=ice-pwd:cc+Og0UJeyl5aUAYHNU2ixY0
a=ice-options:google-ice
a=fingerprint:sha-256 5C:1C:0B:92:6C:E7:87:D1:E0:83:26:2E:D9:90:B2:58:B0:76:D6:AF:D1:E9:38:91:C0:AF:1D:92:13:45:13:AC
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:96 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:96 apt=100
a=ssrc-group:FID 2157921332 2260451967
a=ssrc:2157921332 cname:36oaVisUAzbVEQm5
a=ssrc:2157921332 msid:oHpG0QpIucmqjpjl26NElSfQfQD9Lnetl3Tn bdea0afa-598b-4829-9dfd-ceb9e8c6d23d
a=ssrc:2157921332 mslabel:oHpG0QpIucmqjpjl26NElSfQfQD9Lnetl3Tn
a=ssrc:2157921332 label:bdea0afa-598b-4829-9dfd-ceb9e8c6d23d
a=ssrc:2260451967 cname:36oaVisUAzbVEQm5
a=ssrc:2260451967 msid:oHpG0QpIucmqjpjl26NElSfQfQD9Lnetl3Tn bdea0afa-598b-4829-9dfd-ceb9e8c6d23d
a=ssrc:2260451967 mslabel:oHpG0QpIucmqjpjl26NElSfQfQD9Lnetl3Tn
a=ssrc:2260451967 label:bdea0afa-598b-4829-9dfd-ceb9e8c6d23d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to answer with the ip:port where you will receive the media and add one candidate only with that information.
In the example below, let the port be 22222.

You can filter the codec you want to use. I choosed VP8. Notice that you need to update the m=video line to include only the correct payload type (100 in case of VP8).

If you don't support extensions, you should also remove them (a=extmap...)

If you don't support bundle, (and you don't need it for a video only call) you need to remove a=GROUP... and a=mid... attributes. Also in this case, you don't need to generate ssrc tags, so you can just remove a=ssrc... also.

You received setup:actpass so you need to answer setup:passive or setup:active depending if you want to start the connectivity check or let them start.

Ok, till now, you are only removing what is not mandatory. Now you need to add you part to the SDP. You need to generate ice credentials and add them in response.

Lastly, you need to have your own certificate on the server (it can be a self-signed one) and share the fingerprint on the SDP.

```
v=0
o=- 6548769878907123 4 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
m=video 22222 RTP/SAVPF 100
c=IN IP4 12.34.56.78
a=rtcp:22222 IN IP4 12.34.56.78
a=candidate:234234234 1 udp 768678678678 12.34.56.78 22222 typ host generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:yourgeneratedufrag
a=ice-pwd:yourgeneratedicepw
a=ice-options:google-ice
a=fingerprint:sha-256 YOUR_CERTIFICATE_FINGERPRINT_GOES_HERE
a=setup:passive
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
```

Please note that you need to process and generate ICE (authenticated STUN requests) before the DTLS handshake.

So, it is not a simple task...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it will be as easy as you think. You will have to establish an ICE connection. There seem to be several libraries which should be able to help you with this. You should insert the ICE candidates created by such a library.

For the transformation of the SDP you might want to have a look at some code from my WebRTC Echo server which does something similar: https://github.com/Innovailable/webrtc-echo/blob/master/src/echo.coffee

Comment: When I asked that question I thought that could simply build an ICE candidate containing the servers well known public IP, ubt since then I have read about the exchange of stun messages to ensure a two way link, which is not necessary here but mandated by the specification :/

Will have a look at your example

Answer (score 1):

While you example has candidates with same IP, the more generic case is where the different candidates are from different parts of the ICE environment.

2 Candidates from the Application IP 
2 Candidates from the STUN Server 
2 Candidates from the TURN Server

Latching on to one over the other is based on your proposing equivalent set from your Media Server end and then the ICE packet handshake happens. Basically these are specific routes that shall each be attempted before the end points latch to one where they are able to establish a bi-directional handshake using one particular set. Media / RTP should start flowing in that particular route only.

The previous answer was a normal SDP offer-answer case which is no longer the case with ICE involved.